# Select Random rows from an Excel worksheet with SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will pull X random rows from another sheet in the same workbook.  Below is the code I have so far.  I'm getting an undefined function error on the last line of the vsql variable.

The user will fill in 4 fields on the "Macro" worksheet.  Then, what I would like to do, is for the sql to select X random rows.

This is all in Excel and with VBA.  Is this possible?  Do I need to create a RAND or RANDOM function in my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks......

```
MyGroup = Worksheets("Macro").Cells(5, 3)
MyDealer = UCase(Worksheets("Macro").Cells(6, 3))
MyACE = Worksheets("Macro").Cells(7, 3)
MyResults = Worksheets("Macro").Cells(8, 3)
    
Dim dBcn As New ADODB.Connection

Set wbmain = ActiveWorkbook

dBconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & wbmain.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0"";"

Set dBcn = New ADODB.Connection
dBcn.Open dBconn
    
WrkShtName = "Data"
    
Dim dbRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    
vsql = ""
vsql = "SELECT * " _
     & " FROM [" & WrkShtName & "$]" _
     & " WHERE [Gp] = MyGroup and [Dlrshp] = MyDealer and [ACE Sale] = " & MyACE _
     & " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " & MyResults & ";"
    
dbRS.Open vsql, dBcn

Workbooks(wbmain).Worksheets("test").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset dbRS
 
Set MyData = Nothing
dbRS.Close
```

Comment: I don't think `ACE` supports `RAND`.

Comment: Perhaps `RND` might work? It's been a while since I used ACE, so it's a bit of a guess.

Comment: You may require a helper column on the sheet that is populated with random numbers.

Comment: `RND()` seems to be supported, but invoked only once (i.e. returns the same random number for all data rows). Also `LIMIT n` is not supported. @taller's suggestion of adding a helper column is the way to go.

Comment: I took out the Rand and Limit to see if it would run.  Now I get an error on this line:

dbRS.Open vsql, dBcn

The error says "No value given for one or more required parameters:

I checked all of the variables and they have the inputs they are supposed to.

I'm kind of stumped at this point....

Comment: `MyGroup` and `MyDealer` are variables. Try `& " WHERE [Gp] = " & MyGroup & " and [Dlrshp] = " & MyDealer & " and [ACE Sale] = " & MyACE _`

Comment: And the quotes around strings -if they are strings, like `WHERE [Gp] = '" & MyGroup & "' and ...`